# Returning a Clojure PersistentVector from a Spring Boot RestController

Tags: rest, spring-boot, clojure, jackson

I am trying to return a Clojure `PersistentVector` from a Spring Boot `RestController` method:

```
@GetMapping("example")
public PersistentVector someVector() {
    return PersistentVector.create(42, "hello");
}
```

However, it appears Spring Boot is treating the `PersistentVector` as a function (it is a subtype of `Runnable` and `Callable`):

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector

at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity(AFn.java:429) ~[clojure-1.9.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:28) ~[clojure-1.9.0.jar:na]
at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18) ~[clojure-1.9.0.jar:na]

at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startCallableProcessing$4(WebAsyncManager.java:323) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

How do I tell Spring Boot to treat the `PersistentVector` as a `List` instead (it is also a subtype of `List`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion between list and function can be solved by explicitly calling `.iterator()` on the vector:

```
@GetMapping("example")
public Iterator someVector() {
    // ~~~~~~~~
    return PersistentVector.create(42, "hello").iterator();
}                                           // ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Maybe not the cleanest solution, but hey, it gets the job done!

Answer (score 0):

`PersistentVector` implements transitively `Iterable and List`.

```java
@GetMapping("example")
public List someVector() {
    return PersistentVector.create(42, "hello");
}
```

Implicitly down-casting the return value should do the trick as well.